# Use SmartMenu with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: c#, selenium, smartmenus

I have a [SmartMenu](https://www.smartmenus.org/) in a web app which I need to test with Selenium.  I can find the root menu items by partial link text but none of the sub menu items can be found.

Has anyone found a way to do this?

Here is my code:

```
var menu = IEBrowser.DriverInstance.FindElement(By.Id("main-menu"));
var navigate = menu.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("Navigate"));
navigate.Click();

var offsite = navigate.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("off-site"));
offsite.Click();
```

I get a "NoSuchElementException" on line 5.

I also tried:

```
var menu = IEBrowser.DriverInstance.FindElement(By.Id("main-menu"));
var navigate = menu.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("Navigate"));

Actions a = new Actions(IEBrowser.DriverInstance);
a.MoveToElement(navigate).Build().Perform();
a.Click();

var offsite = navigate.FindElement(By.PartialLinkText("off-site"));
a.MoveToElement(offsite).Build().Perform();
a.Click();
```

This also fails on the "offsite" var.

Comment: what do you mean not found ? where is your automation code? what is the exact issue?

Comment: sub menu items are visible only when mouse over on main menu. So you can simulate move over first then try with partial link text. it may works

Comment: I added my code above.  Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding a wait statement between the 1st click and finding the next element?

Comment: Yes, I've tried a wait of several seconds, even thought the menu appears almost instantly.

Comment: did you try to record navigating with selenium IDE? that usually gives you a pretty god idea on how to handle them

Comment: try putting some `Thread.sleep` between `a.MoveToElement(navigate).Build().Perform();` and `a.Click();`, if this works you can then use `ExplicitWait`

Comment: I am not able to find the sub menus navigate and off-site in your page. where it comes?

Comment: @GaurangShah Thanks, but that doesn't help either.

Comment: @KirilS. I tried using the IDE in Firefox but couldn't get it to record.  Do you know if there's a particular combination of versions that works?  I used the latest IDE and Firefox 54.

Comment: @Murthi The menus are in the HTML, which I haven't posted because it's too lengthy.  I assure you they contain the link text "Navigate" and "off-site" though.

Comment: Is it the same site in the question?

Comment: No, that was just a link to the SmartMenus jQuery plugin.  My menu is very similar to the one on that page, though.

Comment: @KirilS. I got the IDE working.  It uses the same code as above, but By.LinkText instead of By.PartialLinkText.  When I use this code, though, it doesn't find the element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to locate the elements using

```
var offsite = menu.FindElements(By.TagName("a"))[2];
```

I don't know why that worked and By.PartialLinkText didn't.